# simple photo frame widget

Tags: app-widgets, picture-frame-widget

Is there a widget that will show an image you select and quite literally nothing else? No buttons, no switching photos, no sycning or grabbing from remote locations. Just show an image.

EDIT: I'm using Android 2.3.4 (Gingerbread)

Comment: Just curious, why not make it your wallpaper?

Comment: a) I have five screens on my homescreen in my launcher. b) it'd be covered by icons and text and other widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.1 ("Jelly Bean") has this.  I just went to the "Widgets" section, chose "Photo Gallery", and from the popup, chose "Choose an image", which gave me the chance to (you guessed it) choose an image; after cropping, that image is now just sitting there on my home screen.

Amusingly (or infuriatingly, depending on your mood), tapping the image on my home screen does not, as you might expect, bring up the larger version of it in the Gallery; instead it brings up the larger version of some *other* image (in my case, one that's in the same album) in the Gallery.

Comment: I should have specified, I'm using Android 2.3.4.